# Getting error while starting mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

I created a bin folder in user account and paste mongo inside this folder. I successfully created conf and log file also and my server also running. 
I checked that by using grep command.
But if i try to use mongo shell it says"Command not found"

Comment: The binary for the mongo shell client needs to be in your PATH or referenced directly.

Comment: Perhaps you should learn shell *basics* before toughing the console or even MongoDB from the console. If you don't know what a search path of the shell is or what $PATH is doing then you should not touch the console.

Answer (score 1):

If this is Linux or another Unix-like OS and you are in the directory where you put the mongo executable, you need to type "./mongo" to run the shell.  This is not MongoDB specific, it's just the way Unix-like systems work.  If you are in a different directory, specify the path to the mongo executable (e.g. "~/bin/mongo") or add "~/bin" to your PATH environment variable.